# How to timestamp the filename of a new file

Tags: python

Im having trouble assigning a timestamp as the filename to a text file, here is my code.

```
import datetime

timestamp=""
dt=datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp=str(dt.month)+"/"+str(dt.day)+"/"+str(dt.year)+","+str(dt.hour)+":"+str(dt.minute)
print(timestamp)

f=open("sensor "+timestamp+".txt", "w")
f.close()
```

and then I get this error->

File "C:\Users\atave\Dropbox\Python\My Python\changeFileName.py", line 8, in 
f=open("sensor "+timestamp+".txt", "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sensor 9/23/2021,19:41.txt'

I cannot figure out why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not allowed to have slashes or colons in file names. The slashes mark a new directory, just like `C:/Users/atave/dropbox`. Just remove those and use the digits:

```
timestamp = dt.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

Comment: thank you so much, I spent 2-3 hours literally going back and forth on this.